# TypeError when accessing window.google on Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, google-signin

I'm trying to incorporate the Google Sign In feature in my Next app. Here's how I've been doing it.

In `_document.js`

```js
import React from 'react';
import Document, {Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document';

export default class MyDocument extends Document{
    render(){
        return(
            <Html lang="en">
            <Head>
              <meta name="theme-color" />
              {/* This should add `google` to `window` */}
              <script type="application/javascript" src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async />
            </Head>
            <body>
              <Main />
              <NextScript />
            </body>
          </Html>
        );
    }
}
```

And then in `pages/login.js`

```js
import { React, useEffect, ... } from 'react'

export default function LoginPage (props) {
  // When page is rendered, render the 'Sign-in with Google' button
  useEffect(() => {
    window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      callback: res => { console.log(res) }
    })
    window.google.accounts.id.renderButton(
      document.getElementById('googleSignIn'),
      { theme: 'filled_blue', size: 'large', text: 'continue_with' }
    )
  }, [])

  return (<>
    {/* Provide an element for the button to render into */}
    <div id="googleSignIn" />
  </>)
}
```

But this throws an error:

> `login.js:48 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'accounts')`

In other words, `window.google` is not defined.

What's wrong with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the `async` attribute from the script to ensure it gets loaded synchronously as early as possible.

```js
<script type="application/javascript" src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" />
```

Alternatively, you can also use the `next/script` component with the `beforeInteractive` strategy to achieve a similar behaviour.

```js
import Script from 'next/script'

<Script type="application/javascript" src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" strategy="beforeInteractive" />
```

Answer (score 0):

NextJS always prerender pages on server, in this case `window` is unavailable. You can always use `next/router` library. to wait until page loads on client

```
import { React, useEffect, ... } from 'react'
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

export default function LoginPage (props) {
  // When page is rendered, render the 'Sign-in with Google' button
  const router=useRouter() //create router state

  useEffect(() => {
    if(window){ //check window if exist on each effect execution
      window.google.accounts.id.initialize({
      client_id: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
      callback: res => { console.log(res) }
    })
    window.google.accounts.id.renderButton(
      document.getElementById('googleSignIn'),
      { theme: 'filled_blue', size: 'large', text: 'continue_with' }
    )
   }
  }, [router]) // to run again when client router loads

  return (<>
    {/* Provide an element for the button to render into */}
    <div id="googleSignIn" />
  </>)
}
```

Comment: `window` is already defined, but `google` is still undefined.

Comment: @starleaf1 have you managed to work it out somehow?

Comment: i am still facing the problem. Couldn't find google in my window object. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I added the `<script>` tag in the same file as where my google button would be. I tried moving the script elsewhere but that did not work.

```
<Fragment>
    <Head>
        <script src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" async defer/>
     </Head>
    <div id="googleButton"/>
</Fragment>
```

Additionally, I added the callback function `window.onGoogleLibraryLoad` to the `useEffect` hook. I don't know if its supported by all browsers, but it was working on chrome for me. Here is the [doc](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/js-reference#onGoogleLibraryLoad) and below is the `useEffect` code to load the google button logic with `window.onGoogleLibraryLoad`.

```
useEffect(() => {
        window.onGoogleLibraryLoad = () => {
            google.accounts.id.initialize({
                client_id: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
                callback: handleCredentialResponse
            });
            google.accounts.id.renderButton(
                document.getElementById("googleButton"),
                {
                    theme: "filled_blue",
                    size: "large",
                    width: "304",
                    shape: "pill"
                }  // customization attributes
            );
        }
    });
```

Technically you can use `window.google`, however just referencing `google` worked for me. I noticed you were also using `async` and `defer` for the `<script>` tag. If I removed async, I was facing issues when running `next build && next export`. I did not notice any differences if I kept/removed `defer`.

Answer (score -1):

before this line in your code "window.google.accounts.id.initialize({" try using /*global google*/ and then try to run it.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5gEXC.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).